# Sbt task evaluated only once

Tags: scala, sbt

```
def updateSnap = Command.command("updateSnap") { state =>
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  val extracted = Project.extract(state)
  import extracted._
  runTask(
    update,
    appendWithSession(Seq(coursierTtl := None), state)
  )
  state
}
```

I defined a command that run `update` with `coursierTtl := None`

And it works fine for the first time(for every sbt launch).

But when I re-run this command it just outout

```
[xxx] $ updateSnap
[info] Set current project to xxx (in build file:/home/xxx/xxx)
```

It seems task was cached, how can I fix it ?

Comment: When you write commands, you have to manage state changes manually, modifying settings and running tasks changes the state. So instead of returning the same `state`, you should take the new state from running `appendWithSession`, pass it to `runTask`, and return the state from it.

Comment: @laughedelic Return the same state is expected, in order to prevent change setting outside of the task.